# Scikit-learn: What does the MeanShift function return

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, computer-vision, mean-shift

I am trying to segment a colour image through using Mean-Shift clustering using sklearn.

For the following two lines of code:

```
ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
ms.fit(X)
```

I don't understand what the MeanShift function returns. In the scikit-learn documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MeanShift.html#sklearn.cluster.MeanShift), there is no description of what the function returns. What is the `ms` variable? Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

MeanShift is a [class](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py#L297). You are creating an object. You are invoking its [constructor method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/cluster/mean_shift_.py#L399). This creates an instance of MeanShift on which you can perform `fit`, `predict` or `fit_predict`.

Refer to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).